# How to write a mysql query to meet below requirements?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `tbl_loans` which has the field `loan_number`.

Loan numbers are like `0001`, `0023`, `0045`  so I want to find out whether there is loan number length is lower than 4 numbers or greater than 4 numbers

Is there easy way to find out this?

Comment: `SELECT (CHAR_LENGTH(loan_number) <> 4)`

Comment: Review the [MySQL string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_loans WHERE LENGTH(loan_number)<>4;
```

More info about the Length MySQL function (and other string functions):
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_length

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_loans WHERE LENGTH(loan_number) <>4
```

or

```
   SELECT * FROM tbl_loans WHERE LENGTH(loan_number) !=4
```

or

```
 SELECT * FROM tbl_loans WHERE LENGTH(loan_number)<4 OR LENGTH(loan_number)>4
```